# How to do a restore of a large postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-10

I'm working on restoring a backup from on-premise postgresql to another postgresql database hosted in AWS (rds-aurora postgresql, serverless). The data size is 170gb of compressed data.

I earlier thought to do using pg_restore because I can pass the `-j` option, but it's taking a lot of time and space to extract the files.

My file is in the format =  tar.gz  (20200204_data_tar.gz)

I tried to extract and pass it to pg_restore using pipe to save time , but got the below error. Note : backup was generated using pg_start_backup.

```
tar -xzOf 20200204_data_tar.gz | pg_restore
    --host=my-test.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=postgresql--dbname=mytest -j 16 --password --verbose --exit-on-error --data-only 

pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive
```

On-premise version 9.3.4
New Cluster version is using 10.7

Can someone please suggest me options on how to do a restore for this large database?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: I have added more details to my question

Comment: How exactly did you create the backup (`20200204_data_tar.gz`), please **[edit]** your question and add the complete command you used to create that file.

Answer (score 7):

Of course the best option would be to remember how exactly you took that backup...

If you want to restore the backup on a hosted database, it had better be a *logical backup* created with `pg_dump`. So make sure it is not a *physical backup*:

- Run `tar -tzvf 20200204_data_tar.gz` and make sure it does not contain files like `postgresql.auto.conf` or `PG_VERSION`.

Once you have ascertained that, unpack the archive to a new directory and check what you have got:

```
mkdir x && cd x
tar -xzvf ../20200204_data_tar.gz
```

Then check out which dump format the file is and restore it accordingly:

- **“plain” format:**

  The archive contains a single text file with SQL statements, and somebody was weird enough to pack a single file into a tar archive.

  Such a dump is restored with

  ```
  psql -f <SQL-file> -h <hostname> -p <port> -U <user> -d <target-database>
  ```
- **“custom” format:**

  The archive contains a single binary file, and somebody was weird enough to pack a single file into a tar archive.

  Such a dump is restored with

  ```
  pg_restore -h <hostname> -p <port> -U <user> -d <target-database> <dump-file>
  ```
- **“directory” format:**

  The archive contains a file `toc.dat` and many files of the form `number.dat.gz`.

  Such a dump is restored with

  ```
  pg_restore -h <hostname> -p <port> -U <user> -d <target-database> <directory-containing-toc.dat>
  ```
- **“tar” format:**

  The archive contains the files `toc.dat` and `restore.sql` and many files of the form `number.dat`.

  Such a dump can be restored just like the directory format above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below 
1. For extract your file `tar xvzf your_file.tar.gz` 
2. For restore `psql -h localhost -d database_name -f database_file_location`